# Command line arguments to extract a WinRar self extracting archive (SFX) with a password

Tags: command-line, winrar

I'm trying to extract a WinRar self extracting archive (SFX) that requires a password from the command line. From all I can find I should do this (assuming the password is "test"):

`pwdsfx.exe -s -ptest`

But it doesn't work, I still get the dialog to enter the password. I tried a ton of variations of this, but I can't get it to work.

Here is a corresponding example file:
http://xanis.ch/misc/pwdsfx.exe
This file was created by taking the SFX we get from a bank, adding a new file (with a new password) and then deleting the original content. I do not know how the file was originally created and considering past experience getting an answer out of them is hopeless.

Comment: I'll certainly not download an executable file to my computer. Which WinRar version are you using, and what is your operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mofi found out the SFX module inside that archive is from January 2004, the -p switch was only added several years later. Great job, bank, using 17 years old software to give data to their customers...